# Можно ли в POST-запросе передавать интернет-ссылку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

Передаю link — это интернет-ссылка в POST-запрос, когда вывожу на экран содержимое ответа, то поле "photo" — пустое. Если же я это изображение размещу локально в папке проекта, то все сработает хорошо. Получается, то что в POST-запрос нельзя передавать интернет-ссылки?

```
url = f'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key={api_key}'


def get_photo_api(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    link_image = r.json()['url']
    return link_image


def vk_auth(login, passwd):
    session = vk_api.VkApi(login, passwd)
    session.auth()
    vk = session.get_api()
    return vk


def get_upload_url(vk, user_id):
    url = vk.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=user_id)['upload_url']
    return url


def post_requests(link):
> link — интернт-ссылка на изображение.
    files = {'photo': link}
    print(link)
    r = requests.post(get_upload_url(vk, user_id), files=files)
    print(r.text)
    return r


def save_photo(vk):
    save_photo = vk.photos.saveWallPhoto(group_id=user_id, server=r.json()['server'], photo=r.json()['photo'], hash=r.json()['hash'])
    save_name_photo = 'photo' + str(save_photo[0]['owner_id']) + '_' + str(save_photo[0]['id'])
    return save_name_photo
```

Если я изображение скачаю по link и размещу, например в папке проекта и добавлю путь на изображение в POST-запрос, то сработает всё как нужно и поле "photo" в r.text не будет пустым.
[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы отправляете с фото с компьютера, вы отправляете байты фотографии, а когда вы выставляете ссылку, то вы отправляете байты ссылки. Поэтому не работает.